# provision API AppServices using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

is it possible to provision APi app service using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/products/app-service/api through terraform
Seems only possible to provision web apps
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app
how to provision API web apps using terraform.

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? @pks

Comment: Can you provide the code here to understand it better? @pks

Comment: @Jahnavi there is no API App resources type in terraform , we have Web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> provision API App Services using Terraform:

It is not possible to provision API app services with terraform. You can create API Management under web app `API` block with the help of
[`azurerm_api_management`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management) resource provider.

[image]

There is a parameter called `kind`in [`azurerm_windows_web_app`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app#kind) resource provider terraform but `kind = "Api"` is not supported in any versions. The only supported are app, windows, linux etc but not an Api.

To create an API app, use Az CLI command [`az resource create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-create-examples) in the below format.

```bash
az resource create -g examplejahresources -n jahserviceapi --resource-type Microsoft.web/sites --is-full-object --properties "{ 
\"kind\": \"api\", \"location\": \"West US\", \"properties\": { \"serverFarmId\": \"/subscriptions/xxxx/resource
Groups/examplejahresources/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/jahplan\" } }"
```

With `kind = "App"` you can be able to create and deploy it using terraform as shown below.

```bash
  provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "xxxx"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
      name                = "webapp-appserviceplan"
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      kind                = "Api"
      reserved            = true
      sku {
        tier = "Standard"
        size = "S1"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "example" {
      name                = "testingja"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      service_plan_id     = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
     
     site_config {}
    }
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

*Reference*: [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2866#issuecomment-317544291)